# Url rewriting issue on azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, url-rewriting

I have a subdomain, test1.test.com, i want to do a url rewriting on that subdomain to rewrite all requests to point other domain. For example i want to rewrite all request to test1.test.com to point http://www.AAA.com
here is my rewrite rule.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite sample">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.AAA.com" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

the result is not what i expected.

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to rewrite to another domain. Rewrite deals only with the last part of the url (after the domain) so the only way to change domain is to use redirect like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="test1.test.com" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.AAA.com"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: i want rewrite instead of redirect, i want user to keep seeing test1.test.com in the address bar, while the content is from AAA.com

Comment: @AndrejKovalksy is not possible to rewrite to another domain. Rewrite deals only with the last part of the url (after the domain) so the only way to change domain is to use redirect.

Comment: thanks, you can edit your answer with your comment, that i can mark it as an answer.